# Is possible to use Colab Pro in Europe?

Tags: google-colaboratory

we have research project and we would like to use (pay) Colab Pro, but we are from EU (Czech) and you write, that colab pro is only for USA and Canada.
Is there any possibilities to use Colab Pro at EU?

Best regards,
Ladislav

Comment: This question would better be directed to the provider of that product. This forum is for giving technical advice, not including business policies.